# Invalid function pointer called

Tags: c++, emscripten

I use an external library (HarfBuzz) which aborts with an "Invalid function pointer called".

This is causes by the following code (reduced to the absolute minimum):

```
typedef void (*hb_destroy_func_t) (void *);
void _do_nothing(void) { }
void test() {
    hb_destroy_func_t func = (hb_destroy_func_t) _do_nothing;
    void* arg = 0;
    func(arg);
}
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(foobar) {
    emscripten::function("test", &test);
}
```

For now I solved this problem by changing the `_do_nothing` function to:

```
void doNothing(void *) { }
```

Due to the fact that it is in an external library I do **not** want to change the source. I wonder if there is any chance to "teach" `emscripten` to handle this case.

Comment: Which parts of the code are part of the library?

Comment: If this is what the library does, it's a bug in the library. Report it.

Comment: @anorm My guess from the text: `void _do_nothing(void) { }`

Comment: Useful rule of thumb: when you cast a function pointer, you're introducing a bug.

Comment: @anorm The whole code comes from the library, I just reduced it.

Comment: In that case, I agree with @n.m. => Report it.

Comment: @ThomasFischer is the project on a web-serving repository? Could you link the file(s) that you've reduced this from? +1 for the minimal example.

Comment: Emscripten has **nothing to do with the error you highlight**, the cast and broken call are both right there in `test()`.  Your minimal example would still compile and work the same with the last three lines removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely don't want Emscripten to "handle this case". Calling a function through a pointer-to-function-of-incompatible-type is undefined behavior (and Emscripten can report it reliably because it stores function pointers in separate tables based on their type).

You should just file a bug and ask the developers of the library to fix this in *their* code.

Answer (score 1):

This is solidly in the realm of undefined behavior: the only thing you can safely do with the result of a function pointer cast to a different function type is to cast it back to the original type.  Furthermore, there's no way to inspect a function pointer and find out its original type, or even whether its current type matches the original type.  (A data structure including a function pointer plus extra type information may help)

Some platforms may provide a stronger guarantee; relying on that is non-portable.  More platforms may allow it to work in practice; relying on that is likely to cause breakage during future compiler upgrades, as they get more effective at optimizing in the presence of undefined behavior.